# Функция передачи UTM-метки срабатывает только для первой формы в HTML, а не для всех. Как поправить?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Нужна помощь со скриптом передачи UTM метки с урла в инпуты. Он почему-то срабатывает только на первой форме.

```
<script>
      var queryForm = function(settings){
        var reset = settings && settings.reset ? settings.reset : false;
        var self = window.location.toString();
        var querystring = self.split("?");
        if (querystring.length > 1) {
          var pairs = querystring[1].split("&");
          for (i in pairs) {
            var keyval = pairs[i].split("=");
            if (reset || sessionStorage.getItem(keyval[0]) === null) {
              sessionStorage.setItem(keyval[0], decodeURIComponent(keyval[1]));
            }
          }
        }
        var hiddenFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden], input[type=text]");
        for (var i=0; i<hiddenFields.length; i++) {
          var param = sessionStorage.getItem(hiddenFields[i].name);
          if (param) document.getElementsByName(hiddenFields[i].name)[0].value = param;
        }
      }
    
      setTimeout(function(){queryForm();}, 3000);
    </script>
```

Вот сами инпуты:

```
    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="">
```

Как итог срабатывает и передает в битрикс только первая форма в html в которой есть эти инпуты. Что изменить в js чтобы передача меток срабатывала и для всех послудющих форм? В JS не очень силен. Нужна ваша помощь, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `jQuery` - все довольно просто.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getUrlParamVal = function(name){
        var result = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return ( result != null ? decodeURI(result[1]) || 0 : null );
    }
    $('input[type=hidden][name^=utm_]').each(function(){
        $(this).val( decodeURIComponent( $.getUrlParamVal( $(this).attr('name') ) ) );
        console.log( $(this).val() ); //<-- debug! заремарить когда будет не нужно
    });

});
```

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо огромное за помощь!